# java.util.Function source code wildcard boundary usage understanding

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Trying to understand the source code of `java.util.Function`

Have attempted to create my own version of this class,  on comparing my version with source code, found one difference - unable to understand the reason behind usage of a generic type boundary.

**myVersion**

```
default <V> MyFunction<T, V> andThen(MyFunction<? super R, V> after) {
        return t -> after.apply(apply(t));
}
```

**javaSource**

```
default <V> Function<T, V> andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V> after) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(after);
    return (T t) -> after.apply(apply(t));
}
```

this is pretty much the same as `java.util.Function` `andThen` method except that instead of `? extends V`,  `V` has been used.

**why is the type upper bound `? extends V` used in `andThen` method - is there any scenario that will only work with `? extends V` and not with `V`**

note: I understand the `? super R` part is required because without it, we will only be able to chain another function that has the input argument type exactly as `R`

Have the same doubt about the usage of `? super V` in `compose` method also

Comment: Related: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: @Slaw this question is not regarding collections with boundary. assuming its designed based on PECS, the ? extends V is the return type implying value would be read and hence it should should be ? super V right. Can you please clarify

Comment: PECS does not only apply to collections. The concept applies to generics in general. A `Function` _consumes_ an object and _produces_ a result. This is also related: [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/).

Comment: @Slaw, thanks for the clarification. I was of the impression that PECS concept was applicable only to collections as most of the examples use just some collection or other

Comment: its related to some general answers in PECS but difficult to understand. The user has given clear query which i think should be answered and not be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Function` interface, and your `MyFunction` interface, should both be designed with PECS in mind (link [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) already supplied by a comment).

While `MyFunction` can compile and be used with a simple return type of `V`, it can be made more flexible.  This example may be a little contrived but it illustrates the flexibility that can be added by making it `? extends V` instead.

```
MyFunction<Integer, Integer> first = x -> x + 1;
MyFunction<Integer, Integer> second = x -> x * 2;
MyFunction<Integer, Number> andThen = first.andThen(second);
```

The last line won't compile unless you make the return type include `? extends V`.  This allows a function variable to be declared to return a wider type.  The `V` is inferred as `Number`, and the `? extends V` part allows it take functions that return `Integer`, a subtype.

What happens when one needs such flexibility, e.g. when the return type may not be an `Integer`, but it is a `Number`?

```
MyFunction<Integer, Double> third = x -> x / 3.0;
andThen = first.andThen(third);
```

This is useful when you need to compose functions that may return a different type within the same object hierarchy, e.g. `Integer` or `Double` are both `Number`s.  This flexibility is not possible if you limit the return type to `V`.  The variable `andThen` can't be used for both results of `andThen` calls.

Sure, you could force a variable type to be the same as the return type of `andThen`, but there's no reason to limit the flexibility of a user calling your code.

Producer extends, for flexibility.

Comment: Why would someone create a function MyFunction<Integer, Number> andThen = first.andThen(second); when he/she knows that the return type of first.andThen(second) is an Integer.